# Zero cost exception handling vs setjmp/longjmp

Tags: c++, gcc, exception, g++

Assuming that there is a cost associated with setting recovery point, one could optimize a loop like this:

```
while (doContinue) {
   try {
     doSomeWork ();
   }
   catch (...) {}
}
```

Into something like this:

```
while (doContinue) {
   try {
      do {
        doSomeWork ();
      } while (doContinue);
      break;
   } catch (...) {}
}
```

But if platform supports zero cost exception handling, this optimization does not make any sense.

Could someone point me out how zero cost exception handling is implemented on different architectures and is there a way to figure what underlying mechanisms are available to compiler/code generator to decide in compile-time whether to optimize like this or not. And could compiler, for example, optimize it for you if it can assume `doSomeWork ()` has no side effects related to loop?

Comment: Is the zero cost exception handling possible? I don't know but it seems not fully optimized compilation to me.

Comment: You can use http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi to check out a "reasonable" assembly of both solutions.

Comment: @9dan: Yes, it is totally possible. I've generated assembly from the C++ code snippets in my example on Intel Core 2 Duo with gcc 4.6 on Mac OS X. Going trough the assembly, you can see that there is no overhead whatsoever associated with `try-catch` block. There is always overhead when throwing/catching, but if those exceptional situations do not arise, there is a zero cost at run-time.

Comment: You don't see it in the use of extra instruction Vlad but you can see it in the disabling of some optimizations that would happen when compiled with C. The overhead is small (and almost not measurable in real live) but it exist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Zero-cost approach can be used only if available for the target in use. If available, it is used by the most production-quality C++ compilers. Otherwise compiler will use `setjmp/longjmp` approach.

Execution speed of `setjmp/longjmp` is slower.

However, even with `setjmp/longjmp` approach in use, using exceptions mechanism can result in higher performance than checking for return code of every function, as in example with double-loop optimization in the question.

The only way to find out if target supports zero-cost approach and if it is being used by compiler is to translate C++ code into assembly and analyze it. Another solution could be to invoke `gnat` with `--RTS=zcx` and check for errors, if `gnat` is available. But that won't guarantee that it will be used by C++ compiler.

So in general, if program size is not a concern and zero-cost exceptions are available, using exceptions to handle unexpected situations is much better then checking for return code of every function. Otherwise, exceptions can be used to optimize code in certain cases.

Use, but don't abuse!

P.S.: I ended up writing an [article](http://lazarenko.me/tips-and-tricks/c-exception-handling-and-performance) on this.

Comment: I couldn't make out from your answer or your article what the best approach is. If the target allows (and compiler uses) the zero-cost approach, does that mean there is **absolutely** zero-cost at runtime, and therefore your original double loop optimization should not be used, since using a single loop is fine?

Comment: @lori: Sorry that is a not "in-depth" article (I am bad at writing). There is a cost associated with frame unwinding, if you actually throw exceptions, a cost of bad code locality and a large code size (throw generates huge amounts of code, small functions). Functions using throw are not generally inlined, and if it appears a lot in headers, then your binary size grows exponentially into all dimensions. I'd say the use of exceptions must be limited to where it is necessary. For example, they are used to implement cancellation of NPTL threads. Using it as control flow is, however, a nonsense.

Comment: if the expectation is that exceptions will be thrown very rarely, and the compiler/target uses the zero-cost approach, then **all** cost in the event an exception is **not** thrown is paid with a larger code space, but **no impact** at runtime?

Comment: @lori: Larger code size, if not placed in special "cold" section (which is not happening by default) has its impact on performance. Noticeable one. At the very least, functions that do actually throw should be separated and not inlined. After reading the itanium abi specs, then re-factoring hell of a lot of code, and seeing performance increase, I tend not to use exceptions at all. Where I can.

Comment: The link to the article is dead.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're over-estimating what "zero cost" means here.  Here's the [LLVM doc](http://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html) on it; the main effect of it seems to be that the exception and context handling code is built at compile time, so there is no additional cost *at run time* while the execution proceeds *normally*, becoming a space-time tradeoff.  In your example I believe there would be twice as many "landing pads" generated, increasing size and slowing exception handling.

Comment: I meant zero cost at run-time. Not only LLVM, but GCC as well, and I believe all others, are generating handling at compile-time for platforms that support it. So that there is no recovery points set when entering `try` block. If that was the case, my optimization would have eliminated setting that recovery point on every iteration in the loop. With zero cost, however, it adds like two or three instructions outside of the loop. That won't slow the run-time down. But what bothers me is how to figure out what C++ compiler is going to use, setjmp/longjmp or generate handling code at compile-time.