# How does an error handler work internally?

Tags: c++, error-handling, try-catch

I know that there has to be quite a lot of documentation about this topic on the internet.
But doing research for hours without a proper answer is quite frustrating. So I assume I can't put my question in a good phrase. So here the full version:

I'm doing a presentation about try-catch, but it's rather boring to do the basic things. I know what try catch is and I know how it works.
But here comes the magic: Let's assume I use C++.

The compiler will create a read only list on the heap with structures that give information about the functions in the try-block. That includes pointers for start and end of the routine, information about about the object type of the exception and so on. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Okay. Now an exception occurs. The so called error handler (here we go, who is the error handler?) will look up all the data about the failing routine and get the appropriate catch routine. The correct catch is found by comparing the exception object that is generated through the error with the exception objects in the catch.

For example: InvalidCastException (or something like that) is created. There is a catch for that, the error is handled and all objects that are created in the try block are destroyed.

But: How can the program notice that there is an exception? Is this handled by the program, by the runtime or maybe even by the processor (I read something about Ring0 and Ring1, different levels in the CPU oO).

Comment: Sounds like you've read about OS exceptions, and about C++ exceptions, and read them as being the same. They're not. C++ exceptions have nothing more to do with the CPU than any other language construct. If you want to rationalise about exception implementation, you're going to have to specify a particular toolchain.

Comment: Okay, I'm interested in C++ exceptions. But I can't imagine how that error handling will work. I mean - how can my program notice that there is an exception? Do I need the OS for that? Or don't I need anything of that?

Comment: What do you mean "notice"? It "notices" when there's an exception in just the same way that it "notices" when it's time to call a function, or set a variable; it's programmed to do so. The machine code generated from your C++ `try` statement performs the act of unrolling the stack, setting up the exception object, and jumping to the location of the code generated from the relevant `catch` block. It's not different, fundamentally, from how the code generated from a C++ function call knows how to jump to that function. Compilers translate C++ into instructions to actually do this stuff.

Comment: In case of C++ exceptions, you ... well ... `throw` them, so there's nothing magic about it.

Comment: Division by zero and illegal memory access are not exceptions, but undefined behavior. C++ exceptions are always thrown with `throw`.

Comment: @Dialecticus: Division by zero is very well defined behavior and can be caught and handled correctly. With some extra efforts.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: From ISO/IEC 14882:2011 5.6 - "If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @CharlesBailey: If put yourself within a limits of C++ specification then you are right. Though in practice division by zero is handled by hardware by producing an invalid opcode exception and can be even handled in user-level code. Well, except cases like FDIV bug..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx

reading through this stuff it seems to me like the OS / Hardware is handling the exceptions and returning them to my program. Do I understand something wrong? It's still quite hard to understand for me :/

Comment: @Haini: This is why Microsoft documentation should be avoided; it's highly misleading. They're talking about OS exceptions, handled by the Win32-specific `__try`/`__catch`, which is completely distinct from C++'s `try`/`catch`. If you ever wondered why so many intelligent and experienced software developers hate Microsoft, take this as a basic example.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: The question is tagged `c++`, which means behaviour shall be defined according to the C++ standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So an C++ application can do all the exception handling on it's own, without the OS. The compiler creates enough error handling code to deal with exceptions on it's own?
For every try block an exception handler is created. Who calls that exception handler? Who says that there is a problem?
Actually only the OS / CPU can know about a failing "divide by 0" operation? Or am I that wrong?

Comment: @Haini: Correct, except that "divide by 0" has absolutely nothing to do with this whatsoever. And except that, really, you need an OS to run _any_ C++ program, but not especially so for exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of implementing exception handling in C++. First is to use Itanium ABI Zero-Cost exception handling. The second one is to use a pair of `setjmp/longjmp` to handle control flow for exceptions. The first is a preferred implementation for every modern compiler.

The program does not "listen" for exceptions, so it doesn't notice exceptions. Instead, it raises and processes them as part of the control flow. For example, "throw" is always raising an exception which triggers transfers the execution to exception handling code.

Even though these exceptions are heavily used in C++ which provides a nice interface to "throw" and "catch" them, they are also used in C, and even in the Linux kernel.

You can read more here:

- http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html
- http://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html
- [Zero cost exception handling vs setjmp/longjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975504/zero-cost-exception-handling-vs-setjmp-longjmp)

Comment: Sounds quite nice. But I am able to make a try catch without "throw" statement too.
So I got a try catch and a failing operation within it. What happens after the operation failed? Do I set a "failed" bit? Do I fill the exception object with information?
It seems like I'm missing a quite important part that is seen by everyone as self-evident?
I appreciate the links and will give them a look now!

Comment: You can do a try-catch without throw - that's right. But in order to get into "catch" block, something must throw an exception. The reason why you wrap calls with try-catch block is because "throw" can be called by those functions that you call inside your "try" block. Put it this way - "throw" is called either explicitly by you in try-catch block or implicitly by some functions that you might call from there. If operation failed, it never returns. No "failed" bits are set. Instead, the execution flow is transferred to "catch" block (with some stack unwinding). Like "goto" into your "catch".

Comment: See this in particular - http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html#imp-catch

Comment: Lezarenko : I really appreciate your help and I think your last link provided enough information for me! 
Thanks!