# clang devirtualisation and allocation opitmization

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, clang++

I'm playing with a simple code trying to understand how can I make compiler to opimize out allocations and virtual calls. I use clang. I have the following code:

```cpp
    // external functions
    int acquire();
    int do_something(int id);

    namespace {

    struct bar {
        virtual int exec() = 0;
    };

    struct poof: bar {
        poof() {
            //id = acquire();
        }

        virtual int exec() {
            return do_something(id);
        }

        int id = 0;
    };

    struct foo {
        bar *b;
        int operator()() {
            return b->exec();
        }
    };

    }

    int main() {
        foo e{new poof};
        return e();
    }
```

[When compiling with clang-trunk and -O3](https://godbolt.org/z/7zfIH4) I get following, well optimized assembly:

```
    main:                                   # @main
            xor     edi, edi
            jmp     do_something(int)       # TAILCALL
```

Now, uncommenting the line `id = acquire();` I'd expect `xor edi,edi` to be replaced by something like `call acquire(); mov edi, rax`. Instead, I see that compiler is suddenly not able to optimize neither dynamic allocation nor virtual call anymore.

What's the reason and how can I make compiler to optimize them out?

Comment: At a guess clang can't tell that the `poof` constructor has no side effects so can't optimise it away and therefore has to actually create the object, once it has an object it may not be able to optimise away the virtual call

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what `acquire` does.  That means it can't know what the code will do.  Use `int acquire() { return 42; }`  and it all compiles away again. You basically need to know everything at compile time in order to be able to optimize out run time semantics.

Comment: The seems to be because `acquire` may throw an exception. This [affects the observable behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381162/are-compilers-allowed-to-optimize-out-exception-throws) and prevents optimizing the struct away. Try with `int acquire() noexcept;` and see the difference. Although `noexcept` is not needed for `do_something` which makes me wonder why...

Comment: @freakish Thanks, that's very interesting, I'd never think it may be related to excepions. Although I still don't understand, which "observable behavior" interacts with dynamic allocation and virtual calls, and also, why "do_something" doesn't need noexcept...