# Why is a catched throw not elided in C++?

Tags: c++, exception

Given the following code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw int{};
    }
    catch(...)
    {}
    return 0;
}
```

The `catch(...)` block catches everything, so there is no way for the thrown `int` to be left unhandled. Yet if we inspect the assembly code generated by the compiler, regardless of what compiler we use, what platform we target or what optimization flags we use, there's always an opaque call to a throw function called, exception handlers are installed and the stack is unwound.
Why is the program not simply `return 0;`? Is there a reason for it in the standard?

Comment: in general the standard does not mandate optimizations.

Comment: No, but is there anything in the standard to mandate the throw being left in, or is this just a missed optimization I'm overthinking?

Comment: your code is a very special made up example. I am not surprised that a compiler doesn't bother to optimize it. In general a compiler can't optimize away an exception

Comment: Related: [Are compilers allowed to optimize-out exception throws?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381162/are-compilers-allowed-to-optimize-out-exception-throws).

Comment: Maybe it is not optimized, because in most cases you might already be in a context unwinding an exception, therefore terminate needs to be called.